# Firibird на Mac OS X на другом порту

Tags: macos, firebird

Установил на Mac OS X Sierra версию Firebird 2.5.7.
По умолчанию используется порт 3050 и к базе подключается нормально.
Задача стоит, чтобы Firebird работал по не стандартному порту.

В файле firebird.conf добавил строку с нужным портом RemoteServicePort = 12345.Перезагрузил систему.

НО: Firebird как работал с портом 3050 так и работает, а новый порт 12345 - не берет. Пробовал те же самые действия на других ОС (Windows и Linux) нормально берется новый порт.

Answer (score 0):

По ошибке поставил архитектуру Classic, надо поставить SuperServer и все заработает